# how to select data from table if table names are in Combo box

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I was working on VB.NET and am now switching to C#. I was using the following code to use table as variable from combo box to fill a DataGrid:

```
Dim strTAB as a String

dtTAB1 = New DataTable  
strTAB = cboDTA_TBL.Text 

adpPRJ = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from """ & strTAB & """", conPRJ_NET)

'conPRJ_NET is connection to connect MsSQL Database on server.

adpPRJ.Fill(dtTAB1)

dgFIN_TAB.DataSource = dtTAB1
```

I am looking for the C# equivalent of `""" & strTAB & """`.

This code works perfectly in vb.net, no errors.

Can anyone help?

Comment: so are you looking for a concatenation operator in c#? It is **+** but sometimes you might have to convert to string, first. I would suggest renaming the title.

Comment: This code is a [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: I have already tried with changing & to + in C#. But its not working.

Comment: Anyway the answer to your question can be found here, I expect: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings . Did you even try to google this? It's a pretty basic language concept. It's not quite as simple as just replacing & with +, you've got the escaping of the quote marks to contend with as well. But if you fixed your SQL injection vulnerability you wouldn't have to deal with that. I worry that you appear to be letting the user control almost the entire SQL statement being executed. That is a serious hole in your code.

Comment: (N.B. Note that if you're trying to vary the table name being selected, then parameterisation can't actually help you, because you can't parameterise a table name, only a variable/field value. Instead you need to whitelist the table names allowed, to stop users executing arbitrary SQL against your database).

Comment: oK, If I have a database of 18 tables and i want to populate data grid from any of these 18 tables upon selection from a Combo Box drop down, how it can be done in C# ???  As the above code is working in vb.net and its very easy to use as well.

Comment: In the simplest case you do it the same way as now, just using C# syntax. But as I mentioned it's not secure. You need to secure in the way I've described (regardless of which language you write the code in). I'm talking about a conceptual issue of security, not a syntax issue.

Comment: P.S. Are you aware that there are code converters available (such as this one: http://converter.telerik.com/) which can re-write VB code into C# (and the other way round), and will do 90% of the work for you (sometimes it makes mistakes, but only with more complicated code usually).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this is a bad design, due to SQL Injection, but here's your answer :

```
var strTAB = "tableName";
string myString = $"Select * from {strTAB}";
```

Comment: @WamanIna. Glad to hear it! Can you please check this as the answer?

Comment: There is one more option which is working now : string myString = "Select * from " + strTAB;

Comment: Concatenating with a "+" would also work, yes,but is generally frowned upon, and not as easy to read as string interpolation (the {value} syntax I used)

Comment: @WamanIna. Bit of a long answer, but the short answer is using paramatised SQL. Take a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Comment: @WynDiesel Parameterized SQL is a good general answer, but it doesn't help in this case.  It really needs a whitelist of valid table names, or at least validation that the table name only contains letters, numbers, and underscores (and then make sure you put [] around the name).

Comment: @BryceWagner, personally, I wouldn't use dynamic SQL at all. I would rather only use stored procs, or if not that, only use generated code by the DAL.

Answer (score 0):

Although, normally you would never concatenate strings to build an Sql statement, you do not need to be concerned about Sql Injection if your combo box `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDownList`. This is essentially "limit to list" but it is **NOT** the default setting.

The `using` statements ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed.

I not sure what the the double quotes around the table name are supposed to do but in Sql Server the identifier delimiters are square brackets. ( [ ] )

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "Select * From [" + cboDTA_TBL.Text + "];";
        DataTable dtTAB1 = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conPRJ_NET = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adpPRJ = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conPRJ_NET))
            {
                adpPRJ.Fill(dtTAB1);
            }
        }
        dgFIN_TAB.DataSource = dtTAB1;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I use a MySQL command like this:

```
string db_name= "test";
string db_table = "table";
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + db_name+ "." + db_table + " WHERE ID = "ID";";
// sometimes you need the: ' around the string-variables
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM '" + db_name+ "." + db_table + "' WHERE ID = "ID";";
```

Comment: and how is MySQL relevant to a SQL Server question? I agree you've shown the string concatenation syntax for C#, so maybe focus on that (and use the OP's code, not some random bit of yours) in your description instead. Make your answer _relevant_, not a generic copy and paste example